# Incompatible types (from closure to logical) in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have been trying to download some data from textInput in Shiny but I cannot manage to do it. Whenever I try I get the following error (or some things about reactive that I dealt with in this code) :

```
Error in x[[jj]][iseq] <- vjj : 
incompatible types (from closure to logical) in subassignment type fix
```

For my code there is the server part :

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
# Our dataset
Intro <- matrix(nrow=1,ncol=2)
Intro<-data.frame(Intro)
BV<-reactive({input$bassinVersant})
C<-reactive({input$calcul})
colnames(Intro)<-c("Bassinversant","Calcul")
Intro[1,1]<-BV
Intro[1,2]<-C
  
output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
filename = function() {
paste("Globales", ".tsv", sep="")
},
content = function(file) {
write.csv(Intro, file)
}
)
})
```

and there is the part where I input in the ui :

```
textInput("bassinVersant", "Nom du bassin versant", value="A compléter"),
textInput("calcul", "Nom Calcul", value="A compléter"),
```

Comment: You don't need to make reactive copies of `input$bassinVersant` and `input$calcul`.  They're reactive already.  So you can just write `Intro[1,1] <- input$bassinVersant`, though you will need to wrap the assignment in an `observe` or similar.  If you want to continue using `BV`, try `Intro[1,1]<-BV()`.   [`BV` is a reactive function, `BV()` is the reactive function's value.]

Comment: Oh thank you for this fast reply. I am new to shiny I am kind of disturbed to how I should put the observer in my code even I have tried this considering the error message "Do you need to wrap inside reactive() or observer()?" before